# Location does not show

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I have this class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    int f=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
       setUpMapIfNeeded();

           }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Log.d("DanT", "location changed");
        //if(f==1)
       // {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
           // f=2;
        //}

        String Text = "My current location is: " +
                "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() +
                "Longitud = " + location.getLongitude();

        TextView txtgps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loc_textView);

        txtgps.setText(Text);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

I can see the map, but no text on the location.

Comment: You didn't used LocationManager .. are you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//You need to create a location manager object and request location updates or getlastknownlocation

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, this);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, this);
                } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
                    Log.i("", "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    Log.d("", "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocationManager` to get access the Location related data and Instantiate it by :

```
LocationManager  mLocationmanager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

And get Location object from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or `GPS_PROVIDER`. I would recommend to get location data from networkprovider as i uses less battery than GPS (as per [android official document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates) ).

Now get your location by calling

```
Double mUserlatitude = location.getLatitude();
Double mUserlongitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Complete Snippet as follows :

```
LocationManager  mLocationmanager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = mLocationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Double mUserlatitude = location.getLatitude();
Double mUserlongitude = location.getLongitude();
Log.d("Latitude",""+mUserlatitude);
Log.d("Latitude",""+mUserlongitude );
```